# Writing 64bit Interfaces in Delphi

Tags: delphi, interface, 32bit-64bit

I wrote .pas 32bit DLL interface in Delphi like this:

uses:

```
 {$IFDEF WIN32}
 Windows;
 {$ELSE}
 Wintypes, WinProcs;
 {$ENIF}
```

interface:

```
function PI_InterfaceSetupDlg(const szRegKeyName: PChar): LongInt cdecl  {$IFDEF WIN32} stdcall {$ENDIF};
```

implementation:

```
function PI_InterfaceSetupDlg; external 'PI_GCS2_DLL.DLL';
```

It works on 32bit Widnows but I must write something like this for 64bit, I have 64bit dll but I don't know which Windows components it must use and how declare functions for 64bits. Does 64bit Windows use stdcall? What kind of variables I must to use?

Sorry for chaotic post, I'm new on Stack.

Comment: FWIW, the first block of code that declares `PI_InterfaceSetupDlg` does not compile. Are you sure you posted the real code.

Comment: Yes, It opens window to choose conection interface beetween pc and and optical stage controller but returns error dialog with random characters.

Comment: That comment makes no sense to me.

Comment: Code compiles without warnings and errors, so I think there are problems with handlers size.

Comment: No, the code in the question does not compile. Your code might compile, but you've introduced a typo. Your real problem is that your code only works when you compile on a Delphi version for which `PChar` is an alias to `PAnsiChar`. But you are now trying to compile on a Delphi where `PChar` is an alias to `PWideChar`. You need to fix that problem before worrying about 64 bit. Make sure that your code is correct on 32 bit before dealing with 64 bit. You really should read my answer more closely now that I have updated it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**tl;dr** Your main problem is that you are passing 16 bit text to a function that expects 8 bit text because you have upgraded Delphi and the meaning of `PChar` has changed.

---

First of all, you can forget about `WinTypes` and `WinProcs`. These date back to 16 bit Delphi. You surely are not compiling on Delphi 1 so change the first block of code to:

```
uses
  Windows;
```

On 32 bit Windows, there are a variety of calling conventions available. Delphi supports `stdcall`, `cdecl`, `register` and `safecall`. Of these `safecall` is for COM and `register` is a Delphi specific register based calling convention. So for interop the choice comes down to `stdcall` and `cdecl`.

On 64 bit Windows there is only one calling convention and the compiler simply ignores any specification of calling convention that you make. If your 32 bit code uses `cdecl` then the declaration of that function should be:

```
function PI_InterfaceSetupDlg(szRegKeyName: PChar): LongInt; cdecl;
```

This declaration can be used for both 32 and 64 bit builds. When compiling for 64 bit the `cdecl` is simply ignored by the compiler.

Similarly, if the 32 bit code uses `stdcall` then the declaration should be:

```
function PI_InterfaceSetupDlg(szRegKeyName: PChar): LongInt; stdcall;
```

One of the goals you should bear in mind is that you should endeavour not to need conditional code to switch behaviour between 32 and 64 bit. The design of 64 bit Windows and the Delphi 64 bit compiler was well thought out and this goal is quite achievable.

The vast majority of data types are exactly the same on 32 bit and 64 bit. For instance, `Integer` is a signed 32 bit integer on both platforms. Pointers are obviously different sizes, but the semantics are exactly the same. So if you use `PChar` on 32 bit, you use `PChar` on 64 bit too.

One type that does vary significantly across platforms is `NativeInt`. It is 32 bits wide on 32 bit, and 64 bits wide on 64 bit. Its unsigned counterpart `NativeUInt` behaves in the same way. These types are very poorly named. They are really just pointer sized integers and should, in my view, be named `IntPtr` and `UIntPtr`. These types are typically used to declare handles. That is integer types that represent opaque pointers. You might find `NativeInt` used for Windows handle types. That's not the only way to declare those types, and it is quite easy to argue that `type Pointer` would be a better choice.

If you want to take a look at how interop interacts with 32 and 64 bit platforms, have a read of the `Windows` unit. You will find very little conditional code there.

---

A websearch for `PI_InterfaceSetupDlg` reveals this:

```
long PI_FUNC_DECL PI_InterfaceSetupDlg(const char* szRegKeyName);
```

This means that the function accepts 8 bit text. In your version of Delphi (a version that contains the 64 bit compiler), `PChar` is an alias to `PWideChar`. That is 16 bit text. So you need to be explicit and use `PAnsiChar`. So, although you state that your code works under 32 bit, that is not the case. My guess is that you originally developed the code on an older version of Delphi where `PChar` was an alias to `PAnsiChar`.

As for the calling convention, you need to understand how `PI_FUNC_DECL` expands. It is defined here:

```
#ifdef WIN32
    #undef PI_FUNC_DECL
    #ifdef PI_GCS2_DLL_STATIC
        #define PI_FUNC_DECL WINAPI
    #else
        #ifdef PI_DLL_EXPORTS
            #ifndef UNKNOWN_GCS_DLL
                #define PI_FUNC_DECL __declspec(dllexport) WINAPI
            #else
                #define PI_FUNC_DECL WINAPI
            #endif
        #else
            #define PI_FUNC_DECL __declspec(dllimport) WINAPI
        #endif
    #endif
#else
    #define PI_FUNC_DECL
#endif
```

It can be seen that on Windows, the calling convention is `WINAPI` which is a macro that expands to `__stdcall`. So, the final Delphi declaration is:

```
function PI_InterfaceSetupDlg(szRegKeyName: PAnsiChar): Longint; stdcall;
```

---

Your main issue now is to get your code to work with the Unicode aware version of Delphi that you are migrating to. The main issue you face is that your code has not yet been ported to Unicode Delphi. Do that under the 32 bit compiler. Once you have that working, switching to 64 bit should be trivial and involve no code changes at all.

Comment: Yeah, well, tl;dr. <g> I removed my comment.

Comment: I've changed Chars to AnsiChars and It works. Thanks.